# Laravel, passing parameters to livewire form view give syntax error

Tags: laravel-5, syntax-error, parameter-passing, laravel-livewire

I have this route:

```
Route::get("/bourse/add/{user}", function (User $user) {
     return view("bourse.new")->with('user', $user);    
})->name("bourse-add");
```

My new.blade.php file loads the form with livewire.
according to the documentation (https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components), I can insert my user id as a parameter like this:

```
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">{{ __('Bourse') }} {{$user->first_name}} {{$user->last_name}}</x-slot>
    @livewire('bourse.form', ['id'=> $user->id])
</x-app-layout>
```

but, however it is functional and the object "bourse" created is well assigned to my user,  the comma is refused by IDE and therefore my parameter which comes after.

```
public function mount($reference = '', $id = null){
     if (!is_null($id)){
          $this->id_user=$id;
     }else{
          $this->id_user = Auth::id();
     }
    ...
```

have you had this problem and is there any other syntax that is not reported as error?

Comment: make optional the $reference parameter, the component is specting 2 parameters and in @livewire directive you're binding only one, the 'id'

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what exact error are you getting? And is it just the editor telling you that, or does it actually produce that error when you load the page?